# Is there a free library type reboot software

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, automation, reboot, libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Windows 7 app to enforce user time restrictions or Steady State alternative](https://superuser.com/questions/279872/free-windows-7-app-to-enforce-user-time-restrictions-or-steady-state-alternative)

I am setting up a community computer center and I need to set the Windows-7 PC's to reboot 59 minutes after a user logs in. Is there a way to do this? Basically when users login, they will be logged off in 59 minutes.

Comment: `shutdown -l -f -t 3540` (forces logoff and closes all running applications in 3540 seconds (59mins)) [builtin Windows functionality, no 3rd party software required]

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/questions/184302/how-can-i-limit-the-usage-time-for-an-user-profile-in-windows http://superuser.com/questions/301273/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-total-time-a-user-can-be-logged-in-on-windows-xp-pro http://superuser.com/questions/350998/force-user-logoff-script-for-windows-7 http://superuser.com/questions/290944/how-to-force-shutdown-at-predefined-time-in-administrator-account